# Very short math question derivatives?

Tags: derivatives

If we have $2x+p+ (2x+p)\cdot \dfrac {dp}{dx} =0$
we express it $\left(\dfrac {dp}{dx} + 1\right) \cdot(2x+p)=0$

What if we have $\;0 =p+ \left[(2x)- \dfrac 1p\right]\cdot \dfrac {dp}{dx}$
how can we express it like the upper form?
I am in the middle of a VERY long exercise and I need this please.

Comment: You can express it in exact form as $(p^2) dx + (2x p -1)dp = 0$

Comment: I love you,my virtual soulmate.You complete me.(Literally).

Comment: You are very kind, but MSE is OUR virtual soulmate! :-) Regards

Comment: Ha! That was smart.